# How do I load multiple images in SwiftUI?

Tags: image, swiftui, load

Currently I have an imageloader that loads images from a url. But all the images are the same. Does anyone know what i do wrong?

```
@State var outfitimage: UIImage?

// .... a lot of lines in between ..... 


        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.displayname.capitalized)
                        .font(.title3)
                    Image(uiImage: outfitimage!)
                        .resizable()
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                }
                .onAppear{
                    downloadimage(imagename: item.user)
                }

            }
        }


// .... a lot of lines in between ....

func downloadimage(imagename: String) {
    let userimage = "outfits/" + (imagename) + ".jpg"

    Storage.storage().reference().child(userimage).getData(maxSize: 1048576) {
        (imageDataMyOutfit, Error) in
        if let Error = Error {
            print("an error accured: " + Error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let imageDataMyOutfit = imageDataMyOutfit {
                self.outfitimage = UIImage(data: imageDataMyOutfit)
            } else {
                print("couldn't unwrap image data")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It uses Firebase storages where all the images are stored. I really don't know what I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one @State variable with a `UIImage`, so every time a new image loads from your `downloadimage` function, it writes over that one value.

You could solve this in a couple of ways:

1. Make a dictionary with a key of the `imagename` (what you're currently passing into `download image` and a value of `UIImage`. Then, pull dynamically from that dictionary. I'd also consider moving all of this into an `ObservableObject`
2. Encapsulate each Image in its own child view with a @State variable that maintains its loading state.

The first version might look something like this:

```
class ImagesLoader : ObservableObject {
    @Published var images : [String:UIImage] = [:]
    
    func downloadImage(imagename: String) {
        let userimage = "outfits/" + (imagename) + ".jpg"
        
        if self.images[imagename] != nil { return }
        
        Storage.storage().reference().child(userimage).getData(maxSize: 1048576) {
            (imageDataMyOutfit, Error) in
            if let Error = Error {
                print("an error accured: " + Error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let imageDataMyOutfit = imageDataMyOutfit, let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageDataMyOutfit) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.images[imagename] = uiImage
                    }
                } else {
                    print("couldn't unwrap image data")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var imagesLoader = ImagesLoader()
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.displayname.capitalized)
                        .font(.title3)
                    if let uiImage = imagesLoader.images[item.user] {
                        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear{
                    imagesLoader.downloadImage(imagename: item.user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not displaying the `Image` view unless there's an image present. In your current code, by using `!` to force unwrap the `UIImage?`, you'll cause a crash if it's ever `nil`.

Also worth pointing out that in a real-world situation, you'd probably want to do more cacheing of the images, error handling, etc. You could look into a framework for doing this, like https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI

Comment: Thanks for your great response. I do get three errors in the onAppear{} block. (1)Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<Subject>' (2) Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'ObservedObject<ImagesLoader>.Wrapper' Insert ($) (3) Value of type 'ImagesLoader' has no dynamic member 'downloadimage' using key path from root type 'ImagesLoader'.          Is there anything wrong in my code that can cause these errors? Also thanks for that great github link. I'm reading it as we speak.

Comment: downloadImage should be camel case (capital I in the middle) -- my mistake in the original. If that doesn't fix it, please update your updated code so I can see *exactly* what you have.